# GAS: Script authorization via custom UI menu fails with "You do not have access to perform that action."

Tags: google-apps-script, menu, authorization, cross-domain

I have a spreadsheet with a bound script that tries to identify users currently making edits to the sheet, and appends edit info into specified columns of the sheet.

It seems that users always have to undergo the initial script authorization (that Google popup that asks for permissions)  by opening the Script Editor and running a function manually via the "play" button. Invoking the function via a custom UI menu doesn't work and throws an error: "You do not have access to perform that action. Please ask the owner of this item to grant access to you."

Is there any way to invoke authorization in a more user-friendly way that doesn't require the users opening the Scripts Editor?

I thought making the menu was the point of that (manual execution vs. onEdit() or onOpened() triggered execution), but as it stands, this workaround is useless - I don't need the menu if the users have to open the Editor to achieve the same thing.

Full code:

```
function onEdit(e) {      
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var labels = e.source.getRangeByName("labels");

  if (labels == null) {
    Logger.log("Error: couldn't find named range 'labels'!");
    return; 
  }

  var found = false; 

  for(var i = 1; i <= labels.getNumColumns(); i++){
    if (labels.getCell(1,i).getValue() == "last edit") { 
      found = true;
      break; 
    }
  }

  if (!found) {
    Logger.log("Error: couldn't find column 'last edit'!");
    return; 
  }  

  var minrow = labels.getRowIndex();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var row = range.getRowIndex();

  // don't track edits above the labels
  if (row <= minrow) { return; }

  var range_depth = range.getNumRows();  
  var rangeA1 = range.getA1Notation();  
  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm");

  // the elegant way - requires the sheet owner and users to be on the same domain:
  // var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  // the workaround - requires the user to identify themselves manually:
  var user = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("ID");
  if (user == null) {
    Browser.msgBox('Current user unidentified. Run the identification script via the "Edit tracking" menu (next to "Help").');
    user = 'unknown';
  } 

  for (var j = 0; j < range_depth; j++) {
    sheet.getRange(row+j, i).setValue(timestamp);
    sheet.getRange(row+j, i+1).setValue(user);
    sheet.getRange(row+j, i+2).setValue(rangeA1); 
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}


function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Edit tracking')
      .addItem('Identify current user', 'showIdentify')
      .addItem('Forget current user', 'showForget')  
      .addToUi(); 
}

function showIdentify() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var result = ui.prompt(
      'Edit tracking',
      'Please enter your name:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();

  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
     PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty("ID", text);
  } else {
    ui.alert('Look, you\'re not dodging this, I\'ll nag you again on the next edit.');
  } 
}

function showForget() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  PropertiesService.getUserProperties().deleteProperty("ID");  
  ui.alert('You\'re anonymous now.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like a bug in google sheets that the script is not shared along with the sheet.

But to make it more user friendly you can

A) publicly share your sheet (Anyone on the internet can find and edit) or

B) (using "anyone with the link can edit" sharing) In the script editor get the share link File->Share... and have the user open that link.

Then it will work.